# Why the node's name in the console is different that the one in .launch file?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am working with the *bebop_driver*  package and running the *bebop_driver_node*.

The ***bebop_node.launch*** file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <arg name="namespace" default="bebop" />
    <arg name="ip" default="10.202.0.1" />
    <arg name="drone_type" default="bebop2" /> <!-- available drone types: bebop1, bebop2 -->
    <arg name="config_file" default="$(find bebop_driver)/config/defaults.yaml" />
    <arg name="camera_info_url" default="package://bebop_driver/data/$(arg drone_type)_camera_calib.yaml" />
    <group ns="$(arg namespace)">
        <node pkg="bebop_driver" name="bebop_driver" type="bebop_driver_node" output="screen">
            <param name="camera_info_url" value="$(arg camera_info_url)" />
            <param name="bebop_ip" value="$(arg ip)" />
            <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg config_file)" />
        </node>
        <include file="$(find bebop_description)/launch/description.launch" />

    </group>
</launch>
```

But when I run `rosnode list` I receive :

`/bebop/bebop_driver`

Since I am trying to use the `rospy.init_node('node_name')` this is a problem because I cant type a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace and name of your node is defined in the launch file. You can find the documentation at [thr ROS wiki: roslaunch/XML](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML).

**Namespace:**

Since you are using a group, the node will be placed in it's namespace, defined by the *ns* attribute:

```
<group ns="$(arg namespace)">
```

In your case the namespace is defined by the argument `namespace` which is *bebop* by default:

```
<arg name="namespace" default="bebop" />
```

Note that multiple and nested groups are also possible to create namespaces.

**Node name:**

The node name is specified by its *name* attribute:

```
<node [...] name="bebop_driver" [...]
```

The result is *bebop/bebop_driver* what you can see by calling *rosnode list*.

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the   **bebop_node.launch**  in order to obtain _bebop_driver_ as result when calling  _rosnode list_ ?

Comment: Sure, this is possible by removing the `group` around the node.

Comment: Could you explain how ?

Comment: Just remove the two lines `<group ns="$(arg namespace)">` and `</group>`